# How can I use Html.RenderPartial to get value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, render

I have this My view

```
@model WebSite.Models.mymodelModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "AudioPlayer2"; }
<div>    
    @{Html.RenderAction("AudioPlayer", "mycontroller", new { storyId = 3027, className = "" });}
</div>
```

this is my complete view and 
this method in my controller

```
 public PartialViewResult Audioplayer2()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

after that it calls another method in controller which name is `Audioplayer`

but the probelm is I set StoryId static in

`@{Html.RenderAction("AudioPlayer", "mycontroller", new { storyId = 3027, className = "" });}`
but the correct way to get the `storyId` is from `@model.str.StoryId` but

The `@model` comes null all the time. So, how can I use `Html.RenderPartial` to get the `@model.str.storyId` which I can get from controller as

```
 List<str> rtn = new List<str>();
 rtn = GetLatestEpisodes(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1);
```

`storyId` is the `rtn.stroryId`

but until this moment I can't get it

Comment: if you pass List<str> as model to view through controller so why you added "WebSite.Models.mymodelModel" as model in the view.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas I didn't pass list<str> I need to pass them using html.renderpartial

Comment: Can you please show me the full .cshtml code? Means where you call RenderPartial in the main cshtml and how to pass the model with RenderPartial.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas I update the post , hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access your model in the razor view with `Model` variable and not `model` (Note the capital M, it makes a difference) like so: `Model.storyId`

Also ensure in your controller you are passing the variable `rtn` to the view like so: `return View(rtn);`

Comment: can I ask you another question ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand